# Clang unknown class name 'exception'

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, clang

For some odd reason I am having difficulties throwing an exception in C++. I throw without catching `std::invalid_argument` from the stdexcept header file. I have no real intention of catching as i want the application to fail anyway if the error occurs.

It seemed to be working fine until I #included the function definition class into the namespace of the header declaration. It was added outside of the namespace prior since they are template definitions and I wanted to separate the header from its definition; however, I realized this caused a subtle issue that I did not realized until only recently.

Is their something I am missing? I am using clang btw

```
Project Compilation
.
.
.
.
.
Compiling CPP file TrieTest.cpp ...
In file included from TrieTest.cpp:4:
In file included from ./Trie.hpp:62:
In file included from ./Trie.cpp:2:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:55:30: error: unknown class name 'exception'; did you mean
      '::std::exception'?
  class logic_error : public exception 
                             ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/exception:60:9: note: '::std::exception' declared here
  class exception
        ^
In file included from TrieTest.cpp:4:
In file included from ./Trie.hpp:62:
In file included from ./Trie.cpp:2:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:112:32: error: expected class name
  class runtime_error : public exception 
                               ^
2 errors generated.
```

**EDIT:** A bit of the src
Also I compile with
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11 TrieTest.cpp -o TrieTest;

"Trie.h"

```
#ifndef COM_WORDGAME_UTILITY_TRIE_HPP
#define COM_WORDGAME_UTILITY_TRIE_HPP
#include <string>
using std::string;

namespace wordgame_utility{
template<typename value>
class Trie{

      ...Trie Function Declarations

};

//The compiler may not complain initialliy however
//Templates cause visibility issues with user code and is normally defined in the header
//this is a work around 
#include "Trie.cpp"
}

#endif
```

"Trie.cpp" head -n 8

```
#include "Trie.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace wordgame_utility;

template<typename value>
using TrieNode = typename Trie<value>::TrieNode;
...Trie Function Definitions
```

Comment: _'Is their something I am missing? I am using clang btw'_ Hard to see without seeing the code where the error actually occurs. Did you simply missed to `#include <exception>` or missed to specify the namespace `std::exception`? Or as another possible error source: Are you compiling using the `-std=C++11` flag?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `stdexcept` is a standard header, so this is slightly strange. The code in the header should be self-sufficient, it may have been muddied though, or their might be a mismatch between libstdc++ headers and clang's options.

Comment: You haven't put your `#include <exception>` inside a namespace have you?

Comment: Can you upload a code sample that causes this error (I imagine it should be something on the order of `#include <stdexcept>` and then upload to gist.github.com or similar the output of `clang -E test.cc`? Additionally, what version of libstdc++ do you have installed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies............
I added part of the source I did not want to make the question too long originally...........

I compile with 
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11 TrieTest.cpp -o TrieTest;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a cyclic include in your code.

`Trie.hpp` includes `Trie.cpp` which includes `Trie.hpp`. This is not meant to work in C++, where `include` is a literal inclusion (think, copy/pasting the included file at the point of the `#include` directive).

You need to define template methods into the header, or into a third file, that's all there is.

---

What is the effect of this cycle ? In general, poor error messages, as you can see by yourself.

In your case... let's play preprocessor ourselves:

```
// begin #include "Trie.hpp"
#define COM_WORDGAME_UTILITY_TRIE_HPP

// begin #include <string>
namespace std {
    ...
}
// end #include <string>

using std::string;

namespace wordgame_utility{
    template<typename value>
    class Trie{

      ...Trie Function Declarations

    };

    //The compiler may not complain initialliy however
    //Templates cause visibility issues with user code
    // and is normally defined in the header
    //this is a work around 

// begin #include "Trie.cpp"

// begin #include "Trie.hpp"
// -- empty because of the include guards --
// end #include "Trie.hpp"

// begin #include <stdexcept>
    namespace std {
        class logic_exception: public exception { };
    }
// end #include <stdexcept>

    using namespace wordgame_utility;

    template<typename value>
    using TrieNode = typename Trie<value>::TrieNode;
    ...Trie Function Definitions

// end #include "Trie.cpp"

} // namespace wordgame_utility

// end #include "Trie.hpp"
```

As you can see, it's a mess. The combination of using `#include` within an open namespace and having cyclic includes is downright ugly.

Fortunately, in the (near ?) future, this will be improved if *modules* are adopted, which are just a much saner alternative to textual inclusion.

Comment: Yes and no. The cyclic inclusion doesn't directly explain this particular error. What does explain this particular error is the fact that the inclusion of `Trie.cpp` happens inside a `namespace wordgame_utility { ... }` block, and the recursively included `Trie.cpp` then attempts to include standard library headers inside the namespace. (But I'll not post that as a separate answer, since the resolution is exactly the same as with your answer.)

Comment: @Matthieu M. Ah yeah I figured since the issue began, once I added the the include inside the namespace; however, I did this for two reasons. The include actually does not cause a cycle. However if i remove the include and add Trie.cpp to my compilation list then a cycle is formed I found this is because of the templates.

Comment: @hvd  The second  I added it to the namespace because in Trie.cpp the using declaration conflicts with any other file I add Trie.h to for some reason. I can simply remove the using declaration and type out by hand the class paths, which it seems i will have to do now.

Comment: @Bonechilla: The include does cause a cycle: `Trie.cpp` includes `Trie.hpp` which includes `Trie.cpp`. This is exactly a cycle. The usual way of defining template classes/methods is either to define them directly into the `.hpp` or to define in a separate third file (such as `Trie.ii`) and include *that* file into `Trie.hpp`. Also, I advise against using a `#include` within a namespace, as explained the preprocessor is *dumb* textual inclusion, it has no notion of what a namespace is, and thus leaves a mess in front of the compiler.

Comment: Ahh i see so even though their was no error when it was outside of the namespace the fact that i include Trie.h in the first line of Trie.cpp makes it a cycle. I actually wondered about that but ignored it since clang compiled my code fine and it ran though their were small visibility errors like static functions were made global.

Comment: @MatthieuM. So the proper solution would be to rename Trie.cpp to Trie.ii, place the include not outside the namespace like I had originally but outside of the header definition after endif and remove the header inclusion from Trie.ii. Sounds easy enough and it works but I lose syntax highlight and in CPP their are obvious errors. I suppose when I am editing I simply have to rename it and readd the include for error checking and syntax formatting/highlight. Not a bad trade off for using templates however. Thank you

Comment: @Bonechilla: or you can just put all the template code at the bottom of your header file, or prefer to use `Trie-template.hpp` as a name or whatever. One more note: it is considered bad manners to put `using namespace` declarations at top-level in a header file (it's fine within a method definition) because it infects all files which include the code; instead I would advise you to re-open the namespace.